# How to make a concept to check for a type that is one of several, including some which are templated types with template parameters in C++ 20?

Tags: c++

New to C++, and trying to understand the basics around concepts.

I have a function template that I wish to accept a parameter from one of several types, including a type that is a templated class with template parameters. How does one make such a concept?

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
struct Foo {
    T exampleWithParameters[N]{};
    void print() {
        std::cout << "is a Foo\n";
    }
};

struct Bar1 {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "is a Bar1\n";
    }
};

struct Bar2 {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "is a Bar2\n";
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... U>
concept IsAnyOf = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);
```

Desired / my attempt:

```cpp
template <typename T, int N, typename U>
concept DesiredType = IsAnyOf<T, Bar1, Bar2, Foo<U, N>>;

template <int N, typename U>
void func(DesiredType<N, U> auto x) {
    x.print();
}

int main() {
    Foo<int,3> x;
    func(x);
}
```

The following doesn't work either.

```cpp
template <typename T, int N, typename U>
void func(T x) {
    static_assert(DesiredType<T, N, U>);
    x.print();
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to strict to certain types?  I find it is normally enough to have a concept that checks the type supplied satisfies the constraints of the function, like containing a `print` member.  This lets you extend the code easier as you don't need to modify the concept to add another type that you wish to use.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you for the advice. No I am not particular about the use of `std::same_as` in the example. But I am confused as to how to accommodate templated class types with template parameters. For checking whether a member exists, I would still have the same question on how to refer to such type in the concept definition.

Comment: If you do not need the template paramters it can be as simple as `template<typename T> concept printable = requires(T t) { { t.print() } -> void; };`

Answer (score 1):

The template parameters can't be deduced for `Foo<U, N>` in your current `DesiredType` but you could add a type trait that checks if `T` is a kind of `Foo`:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct is_Foo {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <class U, int N>
    static std::true_type test(Foo<U, N>&&);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool is_Foo_v = is_Foo<T>::value;
```

`DesiredType` would then be using this new type trait like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept DesiredType = (IsAnyOf<T, Bar1, Bar2> || is_Foo_v<T>);
```

Which you can use like so:

```cpp
void func(DesiredType auto x) {
    x.print();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EYTnMEh6v)